# elFinder - asp.net connector global.asax configuration

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to integrate elFinder into asp.net mvc 4. I've seen the wiki for elFinder ASP.NET Connector. But I can't understand some of the config.

First of all is the

In Application_Start add Autofac registration:

```
// register IoC
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
// add other registrations...
// add elFinder connector registration
builder.RegisterElFinderConnector();
// create container
_container = builder.Build();
// need also to set container in elFinder module
_container.SetAsElFinderResolver();
```

_container is undefined, should I just create the variable?

IContainer _container;

Where should I put this definition?

I've tried defining the container, and run the project inside visual studio, elFinder said "unable to connect to backend"

and

firebug returned this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

„unable connect to the backend” could be caused because of:

- you have forgot to ignore route and MVC routing can’t resolve this path (as it shouldn't do so)

  ```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("elfinder.connector");
  ```

make sure this is specified proior to MapRoute statements.

- you don't have HttpHandler defined in your web.config

IContainer is http://api.autofac.org/html/BE4CF761.htm and you can instantiate it in place where you build your container

```
// register IoC
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
// add other registrations...
// add elFinder connector registration
builder.RegisterElFinderConnector();
// create container
IContainer _container = builder.Build();
// need also to set container in elFinder module
_container.SetAsElFinderResolver();
```